# What happens to vertical light in light diffraction experiments?

Tags: optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, double-slit-experiment, diffraction

In single slit experiment, light tends to bunch up vertically the more it spreads out horizontally. Why does this happen?
[image]

[image]

Comment: The slit in the upper image is more narrow compared to the bottom image? In general, the height of the diffraction pattern should be caused by the vertical beam extension, resp. height of the slit.

Comment: I don't understand how you see " light tends to bunch up vertically the more it spreads out horizontally" in the photo.  I do see that the vertical sized of the pattern is different (narrower when it spreads out more, to my eye).   I think the changing width is due to the properties of the detector:  saturated in some cases, below detection threshold in others.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my poor english. My native language is french.

When a beginner do not know the diffraction, he expect to see the projected shadow of the beam on the screen. It is not the vertical aspect that should surprise a beginner, it is rather the horizontal spread.

In reality, geometric optics is only an approximation which does not take into account the wave aspect of light.

In the edges of the shadow, there are fringes that grow larger as the screen moves away. The theory  show that these fringes invade the geometric image if the distance from the slit to the screen $D$ satisfies the condition $D>>a^2/\lambda$.

This condition is verified horizontally for a slit with $a$ of a few tenths of a mm and a screen at a distance of around ten cm. It is not at all verified vertically for a height of a few mm. So, vertically, you just have the projected shadow on the screen.